# Can't handle registered multi driver

Tags: vhdl

I am getting this messege from compiler for all the "busreg" bits:

> topld:  busshift.vhd:  (E463) 'busreg(7)' -- Can't handle registered multi driver.
>
> topld:  busshift.vhd:  (E446) Can't handle multiple drivers for 'busreg(7)' in selected device.

I was asked to do shift rigister that I can put in put from both side as I choose depends on DIR.

My code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

ENTITY shiftbus IS
    PORT
        (
        busreg       :  inout std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        dir,clk   :  IN   std_logic;
        pinL,pinR    :  inout   std_logic
        );
END shiftbus;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF shiftbus IS
BEGIN
    busreg<="00000000";
    process(clk,dir)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then 
            if(dir='1') then --1 we input from right
                busreg<=busreg(6 downto 0)&pinR;
            else-- else is 0 and we input from left 
                busreg<=pinL & busreg(7 downto 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
END behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following line:

```
busreg <= "00000000";
```

If you're going to drive this signal low all the time, what's the point of the other logic?

Answer (score 1):

You are driving the signal `busreg` from two processes: the explicit process and the implicit process `busreg <= "00000000";`. In other words, you have a short circuit.

> A process is a little bit of software that models a little bit of hardware.

So, when you drive a signal from more than one process, you are modelling a signal that is driven from more than one lump of hardware. Normally, if you want to drive a signal from two or more lumps of hardware, you need to be using tristate logic. I think the error message is telling you that the FPGA device you have chosen is not able to implement tristate logic and so it is an error for you to drive a signal from more that one place.

So, why have you written the line `busreg <= "00000000";`? If you were hoping to reset your shift register, you haven't; you've created a short circuit.

BTW: your process is a *sequential process*. The sensitivity list of a sequential process should either contain just the clock or, if there is an asynchronous reset, just the clock and the asynchronous reset. `dir` should not be in your sensitivity list.